# Generalization of Stewart's theorem?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I'm curious about the generalization of Stewart's theorem to more dimensions. [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StewartsTheorem.html) mentions that there is a generalization done by Bottema, but I could not find much information on it. All I managed to find was the [original text of the generalization](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/resolveppn/?PID=GDZPPN002079992) in German, and the only publication that cites it (according to Google Scholar) is some [writeup in French](http://www.sbpm.be/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/QUELQUES-G%C3%89N%C3%89RALISATIONS-DU-TH%C3%89OR%C3%88ME-DE-STEWART.pdf).

Why is there no information about this theorem? Are there other generalizations of Stewart's theorem to more dimensions?

Basically, what I'm interested in is a case where you take the standard Stewart's theorem picture:
[image: standard Stewart's theorem picture]

and find the relations when the side *c* is replaced by a triangle, then a simplex, etc. How about if you don't go to more dimensions than 3 and replace the line with a triangle, then a quadrilateral, pentagon, etc.?

Comment: Doesn't sound like the kind of generalization you have in mind, still see the `Remark` in this post http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1290945/291201.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious thing that comes to mind is that the "simplex" $P, A_1, \dotsc, A_n$ (where the $A_i$ are the analogues of the collinear points in standard Stewart's theorem) is degenerate, so its volume is $0.$ The volume is given by the [Cayley-Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html) the vanishing of which gives a polynomial (quadratic, actually) relation between the $|P A_i|^2.$ Since the simplex given by the $A_i$ is itself degenerate, which indicates the vanishing of a principal minor of the Cayley-Menger matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you expand on it a bit, though? I'm not familiar with the Cayley-Menger determinant, but why would a vanishing n-volume be important if the Stewart's theorem gives relations for the (n-1)-volume, e.g. the length of the line segments in the standard case?

Comment: If you have $n+1$ points in $R^d,$ the Cayley Menger determinant expresses the $n$-dimensional volume of the simplex they span in terms of the squares of the pairwise distances. In the Stewart situation (the classical version), you have $4$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ so the volume of the tetrahedron is obviously zero (since it is degenerate), which implies a relation between the distances.

Answer (score 1):

I give a generalization of [Stewart's theorem with two mention at here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234184/relation-of-some-euclidean-geometry-theorems-and-more-conjecture-generalizations?lq=1), do you give generalization of this to more dimensions?