# Relation of some Euclidean geometry theorems and more conjecture generalizations

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometry, euclidean-geometry

In this topic I want to share relation of the [Pythagorean theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTheorem.html), the [Stewart theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem) and the [British Flag theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_flag_theorem), the [Apollonius' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27_theorem) and the **Feuerbach-Luchterhand**. Since that I posed two conjectures of generalizations of these theorems. My question: I am looking for get a solution of my conjecture.

**I. Relation of some Euclidean geometry theorems**

1. [Pythagorean theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTheorem.html): Let $ABC$ For a right triangle with legs $AB$ and $AC$ and hypotenuse $BC$ then:

\begin{equation}AB^2+AC^2=BC^2 \end{equation}

[image]

2. [Apollonius' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius%27_theorem) in any triangle $ABC$, if $AD$ is a median, then

\begin{equation}AB^2 + AC^2 = 2(AD^2+BD^2)\end{equation}

[image]

- Let $ABC$ be [Isosceles triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_triangle) with $AB=AC$. Apply Apollonius' theorem we have $AB^2=AD^2+BD^2$, in this case $AD \perp BC$. This is the Pythagorean theorem with the right triangle $ABD$. So the Apollonius' theorem is a generalization of the Pythagorean theorem.

  3. [Stewart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem) Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be points on a directed line $l$ in the Euclidean plane, and $P$ be a point anywhere in the plane. Then

\begin{equation}PA^2.\overline{BC} + PB^2.\overline{CA} + PC^2.\overline{AB} + \overline{BC}.\overline{CA}.\overline{AB} = 0\end{equation}
[image]

- Let $B$ is midpoint of $AC$ we have: $\overline{BC}=\overline{AB}$, $\overline{CA}=-2\overline{AB}$. Since Stewart's theorem we have:

\begin{equation}PA^2.\overline{AB} - 2PB^2.\overline{AB} + PC^2.\overline{AB} - 2.\overline{AB}.\overline{AB}.\overline{AB} = 0\end{equation}

$\Leftrightarrow$

\begin{equation}PA^2 + PC^2 = 2(PB^2+AB^2) = 0\end{equation}

This is the Apollonius' theorem  with the triangle $PAC$ with median $PB$. So the Stewart's theorem is a generalization of the Apollonius' theorem.

4. [British flag theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_flag_theorem) if a point $P$ on the plane of rectangle $ABCD$ then:

\begin{equation}PA^2+PC^2=PD^2+PB^2\end{equation}

[image]

- Let $P \equiv D$ we have \begin{equation}DA^2+DC^2=DB^2\end{equation}

$\Leftrightarrow$

\begin{equation}DA^2+DC^2=AC^2\end{equation}
This is the Pythagorean theorem with the right triangle $DAC$. So the British flag theorem is a generalization of the Pythagorean theorem.

**5. Feuerbach-Luchterhand** Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral, $P$ be a point on the plane then:
\begin{equation}PA^2.DB.BC.CD-PB^2.AC.CD.DA+PC^2.BD.DA.AB-PD^2.CA.AB.BC = 0\end{equation}
[image]

- Let circles through $A, B, C, D$ is a line, and $D$ at infinity. Then $DB.CD=CD.DA=BD.DA=PD^2$. From the Feuerbach-Luchterhand we have:

\begin{equation}PA^2.BC-PB^2.AC+PC^2.AB-CA.AB.BC = 0\end{equation}

This is the Stewart theorem with three collinear points $A, B,C$ and $P$ on the plane. So the Feuerbach-Luchterhand is a generalization of the Stewart theorem.

- Let cyclic quarilateral $ABCD$ is a rectangle. We have $AB=CD$ and $AD=BC$ and $AC=BD$. From the Feuerbach-Luchterhand we have:

\begin{equation}PA^2.AC.AD.AB-PB^2.AC.AB.DA+PC^2.AC.DA.AB-PD^2.CA.AB.AD = 0\end{equation}

$\Leftrightarrow$

\begin{equation}PA^2-PB^2+PC^2-PD^2 = 0\end{equation}

This is the British flag theorem with rectangle $ABCD$ and $P$ on the plane. So the Feuerbach-Luchterhand is a generalization of the British flag theorem.

**II. More conjecture generalization-I am looking for get a solution**

We write Feuerbach-Luchterhand with a form following:

Let $A_1A_2A_3A_4$ be a cyclic quadrilateral, $P$ be a point on the plane then:

\begin{equation}PA_1^2.\frac{A_{4}A_{2}}{A_{1}A_{4}.A_{1}A_{2}}-PA_2^2.\frac{A_{1}A_{3}}{A_{2}A_{1}.A_{2}A_{3}}+PA_3^2.\frac{A_{2}A_{4}}{A_{3}A_{2}.A_{3}A_{4}}-PA_4^2.\frac{A_{3}A_{1}}{A_{4}A_{3}.A_{4}A_{1}}=0 \end{equation}

Since the new form, I posed two generalization of Feuerbach-Luchterhand as follows(I check it is true with geogebra sofware):

> - **Conjecture 1:**(First generalization) Let 2n-convex cyclic polygon $A_1A_2A_3...A_{2n}$, let $P$ be a point on the plane, then:
>     \begin{equation}
>   \sum_{i=1}^{2n} (-1)^{i+1}.PA_i^2.\frac{A_{i-1}A_{i+1}}{A_{i}A_{i-1}.A_{i}A_{i+1}}=0
>   \end{equation}
> - **Conjecture 2:**(Second generalization)  Let two direct similar 2n-convex cyclic polygon $A_1A_2A_3...A_{2n}$ and $B_1B_2B_3...B_{2n}$, then:
>     \begin{equation}
>   \sum_{i=1}^{2n} (-1)^{i+1}.B_iA_i^2.\frac{A_{i-1}A_{i+1}}{A_{i}A_{i-1}.A_{i}A_{i+1}}=0
>   \end{equation}
>     Where $A_0=A_{2n}$ and $A_{2n+1}=A_1$
>
> **My question:** I check the two conjectures by Geogebra and see that it is true, but I don't have a solution. I am looking for a solution.

- [See case hexagon](https://tube.geogebra.org/m/1443865)
- [See case octagon](http://www.geogebra.org/m/1443867)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I thank to You. @TobiasKildetoft I want to have a solution for the two generalizations.

Comment: You mean you are asking whether these are correct?

Comment: Yes, I check my generalizations by geogebra sofware. It is true, but I don't have a proof. I need a proof.

Comment: If you don't have a proof then you don't know that it is true. I must say I don't think this is on an appropriate level for MO. Maybe math.stackexchange.com would be a better place. But please actually formulate the full question, rather than just state the conjectured generalizations.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, the OP seems to be saying that her software package formally verified the identity, so that it can be said to be true, but perhaps the OP does not have a "clean" proof.

Comment: @katz Unless Geogebra is a lot more advanced than I was given to think, I doubt it has formally verified a statement about an arbitrary number of points.

Comment: Please see: @TobiasKildetoft

https://tube.geogebra.org/material/show/id/1443865 and 

http://www.geogebra.org/m/1443867

Comment: Dear Mister @TobiasKildetoft I posed some my conjecture in math.stackexchange.com but I didn't get a solution. Example:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441934/a-generalization-of-the-lester-circle-theorem

And 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441953/a-generalization-of-zeeman-gossard-perspector-theorem?rq=1

So I posted the question this here. Because I think it is difficult to proof more than two equestion in math.stackexchange.com above

Comment: Those do not actually seem to contain the conjectures mentioned here.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I edited my question. I thank to You

Comment: Yes. But I think these conjectures at here are difficulte than in there  math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @OaiThanhĐào could you try to clarify what you mean when you write that your symbolic manipulation program verified the correctness of this? Can your package handle an arbitrary parameter $n$ or do you mean to say that the package checked it for some low values of $n$?

Comment: Dear Mister @katz

Comment: Dear Mister @katz The case n=2 it is Feuerbach-Luchterhand ; the case n=3 it is https://tube.geogebra.org/m/1443865 ; the case n=4 it is http://www.geogebra.org/m/1443867 . and I checked the conjectures true with n=3,4,5,6. So I think it is true with any n>1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First problem may be solved, for example, as follows. The locus of $P$ satisfying this relation is either a circle or a line or a point or the whole plane or the empty set. Thus it suffices to check this when $P$ is on the same circle or when $P$ is the center $O$ of this circle. For $P=O$, we have alternating sum of $A_{i-1}A_{i+1}/A_{i-1}A_i\cdot A_{i}A_{i+1}$. Denote by $2\varphi_i$ the arc $A_{i-1}A_i$, then this equals (assuming that radius is 1) $\cot \varphi_{i}+\cot \varphi_{i+1}$, and everything cancels telescopically. 
If $P$ lies on a circle, make inversion in $P$. Your points now lie on a line, after substituting the formulae for change of distance under inversion you see that everything containing point $P$ cancels, and you have again an alternating sum of $A_{i-1}A_{i+1}/A_{i-1}A_i\cdot A_{i}A_{i+1}$, but on the line, not on a circle. Of course it is 0 again.

As for the second problem, it asks for complex numbers. Denote $a_i,b_i$ complex coordinates of $A_i,B_i$, assume that 0 is circumcenter of $B_1\dots B_{2n}$. Then $B_iA_i^2=|b_i-a_i|^2=|b_i|^2+|a_i|^2-b_i \bar{a_i}-a_i\bar{b_i}$. The sums for $|b_i|^2$ and for $|a_i|^2$ are equal to 0, it is already proved. Since polygons are similar, we have $b_i=ua_i+v$ for some fixed complex $u,v$. Then $b_i \bar{a_i}=u|a_i|^2+v\bar{a_i}$. So, everything containing $u$ also is equal to 0. Thus we may suppose that $u=0$, i.e. all $B_i$ are the same, it is also already proved.

Comment: Dear Dr. @FedorPetrov ; Could you give the conjectures with more dimensions?

Comment: Well, first claim holds even if $P$ does not lie in the same plane.

Comment: Dear Dr. @Fedor please see: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224338/generalization-of-stewarts-theorem